# the routerLink doesn't work in my angular ionic project

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

I am trying to create an angular ionic project, so I created a module named ident to put the login and subscribe components on it, and when I create the router to cycle between the two components it doesn't work and no errors displayed to me

**ionic V**
6.12.3

**ident-app-routing.ts And Login HTML**

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'Login',
    component: LoginComponent
  },
  {
    path:'',
    redirectTo:'Login',
    pathMatch:'full'
  },
  {
    path:'Signup',
    component:InscritComponent
  }
];
```

```html
 <ion-buttons slot="end">
            <ion-button (click)="test()" [routerLink]="['/Signup']">Signup</ion-button>
</ion-buttons>
```

**idnet.html**

```
<ion-router-outlet></ion-router-outlet>
```

Comment: Please elaborate "it doesn't work". What exactly happened? Or, what exactly you did expect that didn't happen? Did one page show up and the other didn't? Or, neither of them show up?

Comment: yes only the  login page displayed to me

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning two simultaneous actions to your button when clicked :

- test(), which is called from .ts file when user clics the button
- routerLink, which uses RouterModule for switching to other page

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Please try `routerLink="/Signup"`